# Have WebView zoomed by default

Tags: cocoa-touch, webkit

Is it possible to have a WebView zoomed in by default. Im trying to place and advert in my application and would like it to be zoomed to 100% by default so it fills the space.

Being able to disable zooming would also be a benefit but I cant disable all interaction as I would like them to be able to click the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out how to fix the zoom but I did manage to tweak my html banner code to force it to display the correct size using the following code in the head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px,height=65px" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but, if you are in control of the HTML, make sure it is the correct size and use `UIWebview`'s  `scalesPageToFit` property. If not, you may be able to get hold of the HTML and massage it either on your sever or in your app before displaying it in the `UIWebview`

Comment: its great. i have also same problem. now its working. in my application zooming is not happen but after set the UIWebview's scalesPageToFit property set YES. now its working. now i can zooming and zoomout also.thanks.